# how to upload file into a desired folder in php

Tags: php, image, file, upload

i want the name of the image to be saved in database and the file to be save into a folder of my choice. the image name is setting saved into database but the problem is that i am unable to upload the image into a folder. so please help.

This is the code i am using.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO blog (title, image, content)
            VALUES ('$_POST[title]', '$_POST[image]','$_POST[content]')");

    $target_Path = "uploaded/";
    $target_Path = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['image']['name'] );
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_Path );
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path like this :

```
$target_Path = "/var/www/html/uploaded/";
$target_Path = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['image']['name'] );
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_Path );
```

Comment: not working on localhost. will it work on the internet?

Comment: @PratyushPankaj : 
1- what`s your script absolute path?
2- what`s your Desktop operating system ? is it unix based or Windows ?
3- what`s your server operating system ?

Comment: it windows 7. please help.

Comment: you should change
$target_Path = "/var/www/html/uploaded/";
to directory path of yout project.
in your Desktop it may be 'C://myproject/' 
enter your project full path did you understand ?

Comment: it shows this error                                          Warning: move_uploaded_file(../uploaded/ariel9.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\updateblog.php on line 17